UIKit button is ignoring Taps when onTapgesture is on Parent SwiftUI View
When placing a UIKit button inside a UIViewRepresentable and also apply an onTapGesture to its SwiftUI parent view, you might notice that the button isn't responding to tap events. This happens because the SwiftUI onTapGesture can capture touch events before they reach the UIKit button, essentially blocking the button from detecting those taps.
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct MywebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var showUIView: Bool
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("dismiss UIView", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .red
        button.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.dismissUIView), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        //
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
        
        var parent: MywebView
        
        init(_ parent: MywebView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        @objc func dismissUIView() {
            print("dismiss button pressed")
            parent.showUIView = false
        }
    }
 }

//SwiftUI code
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showUiView: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 40) {
            Button("ShowUIView") {
                showUiView.toggle()
            }
            if showUiView {
                MywebView(showUIView: $showUiView)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 60)
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            print("tapped on swiftUI view")
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
//        .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
}

any suggestions that swiftUI tap gesture should not get executed?

You forgot to include a question in your post.

I had the same problem in UIKit with a gesture added to the view inside the cell. It was resolved by tapping the "Debug View Hierarchy" and watching what could cause the overlap of the cell contents
as shown here.
I had a contentView in front of the cell contents(views/buttons).
This helped me to move content view to the back(UIKit):
override func setUpView() {
    sendSubviewToBack(contentView)
}

